# map pytest to specific conftest location

Tags: pytest, python-3.7, conftest

I couldn't find anything in the documentation and so I thought i'd try here..

I'm trying to make a pytest run a file located separately from the folder where the conftest is located, but to use the conftest.
for example - running a test under **a/tests/test_something.py**, where the conftest file is located under **tests/conftest.py**.

I'd like to separate my tests from the main test folder, and put them **with the code they are testing**, but still keep **one main conftest** file for the entire project.
I would not like my conftest file to be located under the root folder - so I thought there might be a way to add 'pytest settings' in which I can **direct pytest to work with a specific conftest** and map it's location?

Would really appreciate your help!
Thanks!